# Magento 1.9.2. - Change format of summary in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, totals, format

I would like to change the format of the totals in the summary on the shopping cart page, on the checkout page and also in the email for new order, on the customer's orders list, etc.

At the moment Magento offers this standard format to report the totals:

[image]

I would like to change the coin symbol position and insert him before the number and instead of the comma insert the point, like this:

[image]

How can I do?

Can I modify it in such a way that it applies in every situation every time it shows the numerical values ​​of the order summary?